# value of the cells are converted to numbers instead of the "000000" format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of strings stored in an array in the format of "0123", but when I am trying to transfer them over into a series of the cells, the leading is lost. How to preserve the original value and format of the array? For example:

```
Range("B" & k + 9) = abc(k)
```

I tried `Range("B" & k + 9).value`, `Range("B" & k + 9).value2`, and `Range("B" & k + 9).text`, all of them gave me the same thing, which is a number value without the leading `0` for example `123` and not `0123`.

I can use the numberformat function to cosmetically show the ending value to be `0123`, but what's in the cell is still just `123`. How can I include the leading `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that mathematically the numbers `0123` and `123` are *exactly* the same value. So if you want to calculate with them the **must** stay numbers and the leading `0` have to be generated by changing the `.NumberFormat`.

```
Range("A1").Value = 123
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0000"
```

If these numbers are actually considered as strings (eg like serial numbers) which you don't want to calculate with, then you can store them as strings by setting the `.NumberFormat` of the cell to `Text` **before** you write the value into it:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
Range("A1").Value = "0123"
```

If you don't change the `.NumberFormat` *first*, then Excel recognizes that you write a numeric value into the cell and automatically converts your string into a numeric value.

***Note that you cannot calculate with that cell anymore because the "number" is now considered as a string. Therefore the first method is recommended for numbers.***